# How to choose default Input keyboard?

Tags: android-studio

I was developing an android app ,Then i got into how to change key board style.
For example in some apps whenever you want to put type something this style of keyboard shows up as a default style,
so do you know anything about how can i make an editText that shows such keyboard style for user whenever he/she wanted to type in it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably want to set the `inputType` xml attribute of the `EditText` in your layout xml file

The `inputType` attribute can have the following values : "phone", "textPassword", "textAutoCorrect". The one that is in your picture is, you guessed it right, the `phone` option

The Android docs are good enough to display it with some screenshots, You can find them [here](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style)

EDIT: There are many more options as you can see in the image below, you can open the Design window of your app and see the attributes for your EditText

[image: GUI Way]

Comment: Next time, as a good practice, remember to post your code using markdown and not as a screenshot. It makes it easier for people to copy and work on it, in case it is needed